# How I can process multiple notifications in short time in android

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-fragments, android-view

I need help on below scenario.

In my android app I am receiving notifications from server and updating screen UI on the basis of notification contents. Its working fine when I am receiving notifications in certain gap of time but when multiple notifications are receiving quickly (back to back without any time gap), my UI is refreshing many times in short period which causes problems like UI crashes or jerk behavior.
Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Construct a queue of the operations you have to perform on UI and then operate those operations one by one from that queue. That will prevent rapid and consequent changes in your UI.

Comment: Thanks DroidDev. I am using similar approach.

Comment: Then if you are still facing UI jerk problems, then I think you should check, if there is a new update/notification. Then you should stop the old ones and just change the UI according to new one. In any case, what I am suggesting is to make sure, that two UI altering operations are not being performed at on time.

Comment: Yes. I am holding old notification's execution for a second and checking for new notification arrival. At last executing all notifications. Thanks friend.

Comment: Then are you sure that you are taking all the benefits of multi-threading in java? Because, you can divide all the operations between multiple threads, so that your main thread isn't left with much work to do and don't lag when frequently have to change the UI.